# WHy am I unable to add text along with <%# Container.DataItem %> in repeater in user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a User Control which is dynamically placed by CodeBehind as follows:

```
    Dim myControl As Control = CType(Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/mainMenu.ascx"), Control)
    If InStr(Request.ServerVariables("url"), "/Login.aspx") <= 0 Then
        mainMenu.Controls.Add(myControl)
    End If
```

As per an example from my previous question on here.

Within this Control is a repeater which calls a database to generate values.

My Repeater mark-up is as follows

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="locationRepeater" OnItemDataBound="getQuestionCount">                        
    <ItemTemplate>
       <p id='locationQuestions' title='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat='server'></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The example above works fine, but I want to be able to prepend text to `<%# Container.DataItem %>` in the title attribute of that `<p`> to print to the browser like `this is some text DATA_ITEM_OUTPUT`

When I try to do that though, it prints `this is some text <%# Container.DataItem %>` exactly like that, ie, turning `<%# Container.DataItem %>` into text, NOT the value from the repeater code.

It was working fine before I made it into a dynamically inserted control, so I am thinking I might have something being generated in the wrong order, but given that it works without any prepended text, I am stumped to fix it!

I'm new to .net and using vb.net, please could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see the broken version of your code, but I gather you're doing this:

```
<p id='locationQuestions' title='This is some text <%# Container.DataItem %>' runat='server'></p>
```

If that's the case, try it like this:

```
<p id='locationQuestions' title='<%# "This is some text " & Container.DataItem %>' runat='server'></p>
```

Comment: Argh, dammit! Yes, you're right, and do you know what, I *nearly* tried that, but just not quite!! Thanks so much, it's the simplest things sometimes!

Comment: @JamieHartnoll Almost always, in my experience. :)

Answer (score 0):

Following Statement include the server side code in your page code.

```
 <%# Container.DataItem %>
```

> When you Server side code on the page with some manipulation then put
>   it in single quote and  code as you do code behind.

E.g.

```
Text = '<%# "Employee Name:" & Eval("EmpName") %>'
```

so you title markup code should be like this:

```
title='<%# "This is Title  " & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") & "Text." %>'
```

Best of all, the Databinder.Eval syntax is the same for VB and C#.

check this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/07/20/what-s-the-deal-with-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem.aspx) for more details.

Comment: DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name").ToString() worked for me.  C# is defautly strongly typed.  So it makes sense to do it in VB.NET as well!  Huge speed improvement turning both Option Strict On and Option Explicit On.